# Один элемент под другим в горизонтальном меню

Tags: html, css

Как сделать один номер под другим? И как расположить логотип так же как в макете(расстояние между лого и номером 60px)

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuX9x.png [макет]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEDvp.png [мой вариант]

```css
ul, li{
    display: block;
}
.container{
    margin: 30px;

}
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.header{
   color: #fff;
}
.menu{
    display: flex;
    
}
.menu li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
.menu li{
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.tel{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: grid;
    margin: 10px;

}
.nav{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="header" class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
                <a href="tel:+375115555555" class="tel">+375115555555</a>
                <br><a href="tel:+375115555555" class="tel">+375115555555</a>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Услуги
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            О компании
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Документация
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Вопросы
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Контакты
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поместите ваши номера в `div`

```
<div class="phones">
    <a href="tel:+375115555555" class="tel">+375115555555</a>
    <a href="tel:+375115555555" class="tel">+375115555555</a>
</div>
```

А по поводу логотипа сделайте отступы, выровняйте элементы по центру `align-items: center;`